# JavaScript - Array Slicing: based on a filter for different range

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have an array of objects as following:

**Array:**

```
[
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "00:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "00:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "01:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "01:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "02:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "02:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "03:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "03:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "04:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "04:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "05:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "05:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "06:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "06:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "07:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "07:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "08:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "08:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "09:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "09:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "10:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "10:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "11:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "11:30"
  }
]
```

**UI:** It is displaying like this:

[image]

**User Action:** When user select any time slots, like this:
[image]

The Array will then have some checked times.

```
[
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "00:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "00:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "01:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "01:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "02:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "02:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "03:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "03:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "04:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "04:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "05:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "05:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "06:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "06:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "07:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "07:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "08:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "08:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "09:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "09:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "10:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "10:30"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "11:00"
  },
  {
    "isChecked": false,
    "title": "11:30"
  }
]
```

**What I Want:** A list of all time sessions ( start -to- end ), based on the selected time slots:

**output:**

```
[
  {
    "StartTime": "00:00",
    "EndTime": "02:00"
  },
{
    "StartTime": "07:00",
    "EndTime": "09:00"
  },
{
    "StartTime": "10:00",
    "EndTime": "11:00"
  },
]
```

I have tried it a little bit, but not getting the desired output.

here is the link of my code 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngoninit-wvnjfk

*Your help will be highly appreciated !*

Comment: So you are trying to use the design you have to create a list of contiguous blocks of time?  Also, your sample data it should be: 00:00 -> 02:30 etc.  You have the 2:00 block checked, so it means that 30 minute block is consumed, so all your item ranges should be to the bottom of the hour (top of the first empty block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the slot and predecessor and add a new object or update the last object.

```js
var data = [{ isChecked: true, title: "00:00" }, { isChecked: true, title: "00:30" }, { isChecked: true, title: "01:00" }, { isChecked: true, title: "01:30" }, { isChecked: true, title: "02:00" }, { isChecked: false, title: "02:30" }, { isChecked: false, title: "03:00" }, { isChecked: false, title: "03:30" }, { isChecked: false, title: "04:00" }, { isChecked: false, title: "04:30" }, { isChecked: false, title: "05:00" }, { isChecked: false, title: "05:30" }, { isChecked: false, title: "06:00" }, { isChecked: false, title: "06:30" }, { isChecked: true, title: "07:00" }, { isChecked: true, title: "07:30" }, { isChecked: true, title: "08:00" }, { isChecked: true, title: "08:30" }, { isChecked: true, title: "09:00" }, { isChecked: false, title: "09:30" }, { isChecked: true, title: "10:00" }, { isChecked: true, title: "10:30" }, { isChecked: true, title: "11:00" }, { isChecked: false, title: "11:30" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { isChecked, title }, i, a) => {
        if (!isChecked) return r;

        if (!i || !a[i - 1].isChecked) r.push({ StartTime: title, EndTime: title });
        else r[r.length - 1].EndTime = title;

        return r;
    }, []);         

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using js reduce. Chunk array then take first and last time.

```js
const data=[{"isChecked":!0,"title":"00:00"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"00:30"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"01:00"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"01:30"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"02:00"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"02:30"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"03:00"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"03:30"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"04:00"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"04:30"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"05:00"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"05:30"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"06:00"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"06:30"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"07:00"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"07:30"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"08:00"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"08:30"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"09:00"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"09:30"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"10:00"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"10:30"},{"isChecked":!0,"title":"11:00"},{"isChecked":!1,"title":"11:30"}];

const result = data.reduce(({ curr, times }, n) => {
    if (curr != n.isChecked && n.isChecked) times.push([]);
    if (n.isChecked) times[times.length-1].push(n.title);
    return { curr: n.isChecked, times };
}, { curr: false, times: [] }).times.map(range => ({ StartTime: range[0], EndTime: range[range.length-1] }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the time slot dataset and return time blocks based on the current and previous time slots.

1. Just check for `isChecked` and add a new block, if the previous slot was not checked.
2. If the current one is not checked, but the previous one was, finish the time block.

```js
const expected = getExpected(),
      actual   = calculateTimeBlocks(getInput());

console.log('Equal?:', JSON.stringify(actual) === JSON.stringify(expected));
console.log(actual);

function calculateTimeBlocks(timeSlots) {  
  return timeSlots.reduce((blocks, curr, index, arr) => {
    let prev = index > 0 ? arr[index - 1] : null;
    if (curr.isChecked) {
      if (!prev || !prev.isChecked) {
        blocks.push({ "StartTime" : curr.title });
      }
    } else {
      if (prev && prev.isChecked) {
        Object.assign(blocks[blocks.length - 1], {
          ["EndTime"] : prev.title
        });
      }
    }
    return blocks;
  }, []);
}

function getInput() {
  return [
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "00:00" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "00:30" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "01:00" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "01:30" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "02:00" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "02:30" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "03:00" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "03:30" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "04:00" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "04:30" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "05:00" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "05:30" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "06:00" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "06:30" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "07:00" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "07:30" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "08:00" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "08:30" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "09:00" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "09:30" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "10:00" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "10:30" },
    { "isChecked": true,  "title": "11:00" },
    { "isChecked": false, "title": "11:30" }
  ];
}

function getExpected() {
  return [
    { "StartTime": "00:00", "EndTime": "02:00" },
    { "StartTime": "07:00", "EndTime": "09:00" },
    { "StartTime": "10:00", "EndTime": "11:00" },
  ];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```